# Como fazer a imagem ocupar 100% da tela. pyqt5 -python

Tags: python, pyqt-5

tenho uma imagem e preciso que ela ocupe 100%, será o fundo do meu programa, como proceder?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

class Hello_World(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hello_World, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Olá mundo!")
        self.setGeometry(200,200,700,500)
        self.setStyleSheet("Background-Color: #d9b3ff;")

        self.texto = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.texto.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Imagens/fundo.jpg"))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    janela = Hello_World()
    janela.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode escalar a imagem, e usar ela como paleta de fundo:

```
   oImage = QImage("fundo.png")
   sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(700,500)) #use o tamanho do fundo
   palette = QPalette()
   palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))
   # esse 10 acima é a propriedade Window role, veja o manual da Qt
   self.setPalette(palette)
```

Isto evita a necessidade de "improvisar" um fundo com label, e passa a responsabilidade do desenho para o lugar certo (a "pintura" do fundo).

Se quiser que o tamanho acompanhe o `resize` da janela, basta trocar o `oImage.scaled(QSize(700,500))` por `oImage.scaled(self.size())`, ou preferencialmente fazer isso no `SIGNAL("resized()")` automaticamente.

> http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop

Comment: eu esqueci de comentar, mas queria ajustar esse fundo para crescer quando eu clicar no botão maximizar.. obrigado pela resposta

Comment: É a mesma coisa, só que você em vez de por tamanho fixo, usa o size da janela. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: parece bom, vou testar, muito obrigado